# Trick to indent logstash file in vim

Tags: vim

Could you help me with a trick to indent logstash files using two splace in vim, please?

For example this

```
input {
  stdin {
  codec => "json"
 }
  }

filter {
    json {
    source => "Filebeat"
target => "Filebeat"
   }
            }
 output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost"]
 index => "dhcp-%{+YYYY.MM}-11"
   }
   }
```

will be

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "Filebeat"
    target => "Filebeat"
  }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost"]
    index => "dhcp-%{+YYYY.MM}-11"
  }
}
```

This is another example of logstash config file

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/usr/share/logstash/hola/*.xml"
      type => "hola"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/usr/share/logstash/sincedb/hola"
      codec => multiline {
         pattern => "</HOLA>"
         negate => true
         what => "next"
      }
      codec => plain {
         charset => "UTF-8"
      }
      max_open_files => "30000"
   }
}

filter {
   if [type] == "hola" {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "[rrrrrrr][name]" => "hola" }
      }
      mutate {
         gsub => [
            "message", "&", "E",
            "message", "<\?xml .*\?>", "",
            "message", "<BLOCO>", "",
            "message", "<\/BLOCO>", "",
            "message", "<br>", "",
            "message", "    ", ""
         ]
         strip => ["message"]
      }

      xml {
         source => message
         target => hola
      }

      if ![hola] {
         drop {
         }
      }

      fingerprint {
         method => "SHA256"
         key => "433247"
         source => [ "message" ]
      }

      mutate {
         convert => {
            "[hola][CrD_rILrAr]" => "string"
         }

         remove_field => [ "message" ]
      }

      date {
         match => [ "[hola][DT_ffffff][0]", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
         timezone => 'America/LIMA'
      }
   }
}

output {
    if [type] == "hola" {
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => [
           "xxxtal.com",
           "xxxtal.com",
           "xxxtal.com",
           "xxxtal.com"
           ]
           user => logstash
           password => xxxx
           document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
           index => "hola-%{+YYYY.MM}"
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a key map that basically implements custom indenting for your use-case. It works on the larger example you supplied. Probably not the best solution and certainly not the cleanest one, but here you go:

```
nmap <F2> :%s/^\s*<CR>:g/{/+ normal >G<CR>:g/}/normal <G<CR>:g/{.*}/:><CR>:g/\[/+ normal >G<CR>:g/\]/normal <G<CR>:g/\[.*\]/:><CR>
```

What it does is:

- Remove all indentation.
- For each `{` or `[` indent the rest of the file one to the right.
- For each `}` or `]` indent the rest of the file one to the left, including the line where the bracket was found.
- Each line that has a `{.*}` and/or `[.*]` is also indented one to the left.

Like I said, not the cleanest way, but it seems to work. Also looked for plugins to do the same thing, but these do not seem to exist for logstash files.

**EDIT**: I tried to tidy up the commands a little bit, but that would break some edge cases, this is still the best resulting command.

Comment: After add the three lines

I get unexpected indentation. I get

    source => "Filebeat"\n\ntarget => "Filebeat"

but I need

    source => "Filebeat"
    target => "Filebeat"

Sorry by "\n". I do not how to ouse breakline here

Comment: You are right! I solved this using the `g` command to de-indent certain lines: `g/=> \S*\n\s*\w/+normal <<`. I suggest creating a hotkey that does the indenting and de-indenting simultaneously, I edited the answer to incorporate this.

Comment: thanks by your reply, but apparently these tricks does not work. I edited my question and added another logstash config file. The tricks does not work in that file

Comment: Oh ok, I don't really know logstash files, sorry. But I'm working on it! Will update when I have a suitable solution :)

Comment: Much better would be to bind `=` to a function that does this, but buffer-local of course

Comment: True! But I don't know vim script (yet).

Comment: There we go @Juan, it's not pretty but it works, I would set it and forget it :p